# node.js timing http requests

Tags: node.js, timing

I am trying to time how long it takes to respond to requests.

Right now I create a timestamp on the **httpServer** *request* event the problem is that **httpServerResponse** does not emit *end* and the end function to finish the response is called in different locations and I dont want to add this code at all these locations.

Is there a better way to do this?

```js
var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', dispatch);

function dispatch(req, res){
   var start = Date.now();
   // No such event so never fired
   res.on('end', function(){
      console.log('requests.time', Date.now() - start);
   });
   generateResponse(req, res);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could overwrite the original res.end() function and call the original from within it:

```
var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', dispatch);

function dispatch(req, res){
   var start = Date.now();

   var original=res.end;

   res.end=function(txt,encoding){
     console.log('requests.time', Date.now() - start);
     original.call(this,txt,encoding);
   }   

   generateResponse(req, res);
}

function generateResponse(req,res){
    setTimeout(function(){ // simulate some processing
        res.end('hi');
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: yes I was thinking about doing that, I thought that there might be another way. thanks